Number of countable models of DLOWE with an increasing order-isomorphism.
Recently I tried to answer this question by taking the DLOWE and an ascending sequence of constants ($c_1 < c_2 < c_3 \cdots$) construction and encoding it in a finite language with a finite axiomatization.
If we think of our DLOWE as $(\mathbb{Q}, \le)$, then the sequence of constants converges to a rational, converges to an irrational, or does not converge.
I tried to encode the sequence in a different way by extending the language.
The construction that I came up with does not work (credit: spaceisdarkgreen), but I am curious how many countable models up to isomorphism it has and whether it is complete.
Here is what I came up with.
Let $L$ be the language $(\le, f, \ell)$ where $f$ is a unary function and $\ell$ is a constant. Let $T$ be the following theory.

$\le$ is a dense linear order without endpoints (DLOWE)
$\ell$ is the greatest lower bound of the image of $f$.
$f$ is an order isomorphism from $(\infty, \infty)$ to $(\ell, \infty)$.
$f$ increases its argument. For all $z$, $f(z) > z$.

Spaceisdarkgreen pointed out that

$\lim_n f^{(n)}(ℓ)$ can't be rational (it will open up a gap in the range of $f$). But I think ultimately this approach fails from having too many models rather than too few

I don't think there's any obstacle to $f^{(n)}$ approaching an irrational number or failing to converge, but I also know by Vaught's never-two theorem that there can't be two countable models.
I can also see a vague intuitive argument for why two models with the same convergence behavior can have their elements aligned iteratively, producing an isomorphism.
Anyway, something has to give. This theory can't be complete and have two countable models.
So, that leads me to wonder:

Is $T$ complete?
How many countable models does $T$ have?


Partial answer:
Suppose $\mathcal{M}=(\mathbb{Q};<,f,0)$ is a countable model of this theory. We can extend $f$ to all of $\mathbb{R}$ in the obvious way, and ask about fixed points of $f$ there; the cardinality of the set of fixed points of the extended $f$ is then an isomorphism-invariant of $\mathcal{M}$. It's easy to whip up examples of $f$s with $n$ "extended fixed points" for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, so your theory has at least $\aleph_0$-many nonisomorphic countable models.
(In fact we can get continuum-many countable models up to isomorphism by looking at $f$s with infinitely many extended fixed points and paying attention to, not just the number, but the ordertype of the set of those extended fixed points.)

The part that this leaves untouched is completeness, and of course the point of the above is that we won't be able to use back-and-forth arguments here. I suspect that the theory is complete, and that the way to show this is to break an $\mathcal{M}$ as above into "blocks" generated by the transitive symmetric reflexive closure of $$a\sim b\iff a<b<f(a),$$ and use EF-games, but I don't immediately see the details.

Thank you, that is quite helpful. I'm not done trying to tweak the DLOWE + sequence construction to get it down to a finite language just yet, but it is nice to know that this particular avenue isn't promising for fundamental reasons. (I don't see a way of controlling the $\mathbb{R}$-behavior of $f$)

Let $M$ be a countable model of your theory $T$. Let $I$ be the set of elements of $M$ which are bounded above by $f^n(\ell)$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$, and note that $I$ is an initial segment of $M$ which is an $L$-substructure. Further, for every $x\in I$, there exists $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $y\in (-\infty,\ell]$ such that $x = f^n(y)$.
Since $(-\infty,\ell)$ is a countable dense linear order without endpoints, we can fix an order-isomorphism $\varphi\colon (-\infty,\ell]\to ((0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q})$. Note that $\varphi(\ell) = 1$. Then we can extend $\varphi$ to an $L$-isomorphism $\varphi'\colon (I,\leq,f,\ell)\to (\mathbb{Q}_+,\leq,s,1)$, where $s(q) = q+1$, by defining $\varphi'(f^n(y)) = s^n(\varphi(y))$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $y\in (-\infty,\ell]$.
Let $M' =  M\setminus I$. The relation $x\sim y$ iff there is some integer $n$ with $f^n(x)\leq y\leq f^{n+1}(x)$ is an equivalence relation which partitions $M'$ into convex equivalence classes. By a similar argument to the one above for $I$, each equivalence class is isomorphic in the language $\{\leq,f\}$ to $(\mathbb{Q},\leq,s)$. Since the classes are convex, the linear order induces a linear order on $M'/{\sim}$. Let $L = (M'/{\sim},\leq)$. Then $(M',\leq,f)\cong (L\times \mathbb{Q},\leq_{\text{lex}},\mathrm{id}_L\times s)$.
Putting all of the above together, we find that every countable model of $T$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}_+ + (L\times \mathbb{Q})$ for some linear order $L$. Further, it's easy to check that any finite or countable linear order $L$ gives a countable model $M_L$ of $T$, and the linear order on equivalence classes of $M_L$ is isomorphic to $L$, so $M_L \cong M_{L'}$ if and only if $L\cong L'$. Thus there are continuum-many countable models up to isomorphism (since there are continuum-many countable linear orders up to isomorphism).
Given this explicit characterization of the countable models, it is straightforward to show (by any of the standard tests) that $T$ has quantifier elimination. It follows that $(\mathbb{Q}_+,\leq,s,1)$ is a prime model of $T$ (it embeds elementarily into every other model of $T$), and hence $T$ is complete.
